# Multi-window Evolution?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, evolution

I'm trying Evolution out for both mail and calendaring, but I'd really like to have both functions visible at the same time. Is there a way to do that? Separate windows is what I'm thinking, but a split view could work too.

Really, I just want to be able to easily go through emails about appointments and see my availability easily.  I can pop each email out into its own window, but that's a lot of clicking around that I'd prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it, I'm probably going to just pop relevant emails out into their own windows for now.  But it'd still be nice to have a multi-window mode.   :)